# Is there a stand-alone database for Adobe AIR that supports large amounts of data?

Tags: sqlite, air

I have considered [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite), but from what I've read, it is very unstable at sizes bigger than 2 GB. I need a database that in theory can grow up to 10 GB.

It would be best if it was stand-alone since it is easier to implement for non-techie users, instead of having the extra step of installing something like [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) which most likely will require assistance.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) will actually work fine for you with large databases, especially if you index them appropriately. Considering SQLite's popularity it seems unlikely that it would have fundamental bugs.

I would suggest that you revisit the decision to rule out SQLite, and you might try to compensate for the *selection bias* of negative reports. That is, people tend to publicize bug reports, not non-bug reports, and if SQLite were the most popular embedded database then you might expect to see more negative experiences than with less popular packages even if it were superior.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite should handle your file sizes just fine.  The only caveat worth mentioning is that SQLite is not suitable for highly-concurrent environments, since the entire database file is exclusively-locked during writing processes.

So if you are writing an application that needs to handle several users concurrently, a better choice would be [Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/).

Comment: can postgresql be stand alone?

Comment: You mean a single data file, like SQLite?  I don't think so, it is a data folder.  But there are procedures available for moving this data folder to another computer.  See http://nlakkakula.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/moving-postgresql-data-folder/